# get value of key from properties file in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

How can i get a value from properties file based on key in GWT. I have two properties files one is for English and other for French.I want to add a tooltip for the icon by getting the value from properties file using mouseover event.

How can i achieve this?

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an interface first, with the same name as of properties file, extending the built-in Constants interface provided by GWT. Method names must match the tag names uses in the .properties files

This [link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants) might help you. Then get the String in your mouseOver event handler. Hope this helps.