# Does we have to put any .XML tags to include or inherit the .properties files in GWT?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I did the steps mentioned on This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327559/get-value-of-key-from-properties-file-in-gwt)

but the page won't appear and throws this error

```
    [ERROR] - Line 45: No source code is available for type com.cbd.main.properties.UserProperties; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the GWT Java-to-JS compiler cannot access the source of the class. The class `com.cbd.main.properties.UserProperties` has to be in your client package and the source has to be visible to the GWT Java-to-JS compiler.

The compiler scans the source path (defined in the app's module.gwt.XML) and all source paths from inherited modules. If it can't find the source in there you get the above error.